# Update data when property is updated

Tags: vue-component, vuejs2

i have a component with a property "A" and a data property "a" set when "A" is set

```
{ props:["A"], data() { return  { a: this.A } }
```

I also have a mounted event that would set "a" based on a `_route.params.a` thus data property "a" can be set via "A" or "_route.params.a"

My question is.... IF prop "A" is updated why would it not update "a"? What can be done to have "a" updated by either methods?

Answer (score 1):

The way you're defining a:

```
...
data() {
  return {
    a: this.A
  }
}
...
```

is only initializing a with A's value - it is not a reference to A. Thus when A changes the change is not propagated to a. If you wanted that, you could define a as a computed property ( a() { return this.A; }) and the data would flow as you expect.

If you want to set a based on the prop and/or route params, you should probably watch their values and set a accordingly.